# GoogleTagManager error: _avn has no backing implementation

Tags: ios, analytics, google-tag-manager

This simple push to the data layer of a screen view prints an error with verbose logging enabled. This and subsequent calls to the data layer all fail. They are neither logged nor executed.

```
[[TAGManager instance].dataLayer push:@{@"event" : @"screen-loads",
                                                    @"screen-name": [tracker get:kGAIScreenName],
                                                    @"viewController" :NSStringFromClass([sender class])
                                                    }];
```

This is the error message being logged:

```
GoogleTagManager error: _avn has no backing implementation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue was in `_avn`. Our friends over at Analytics Pros took a look at the container and noticed that we had a reference to the built in variable `{{App Version Name}}`. They noticed that wasn't set, and they think it's a variable that is no longer part of v2.

Anyway, changing `{{App Version Name}}` to `{{App Version Code}}` got rid of the error and data is flowing freely. Hope this helps.