# Google tag manager error

Tags: ios, google-tag-manager

I´m having these messages:

> GoogleTagManager error: _us has no backing implementation.
>   GoogleTagManager error: Failed to parse an invalid boolean:

Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're referring to a buil-in variable that no longer exists, see this answer on a similar post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31041264/805337

EDIT: this could happen if you deactivate a built-in variable or if you changed the GTM version you're using